# Ignore inserting duplicated data into the DB does not seem to be working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and LaravelExcel for importing an Excel file that holds a column named "National Code" and this code must be unique in the Database.

So if a user entered repeated National Codes in his Excel file, a message has to appear and show repeated National Codes to him.

So I coded this at the Import Class:

```
    $query=DB::table('olympiad_1400');
    
    $repeated = [];
    
    foreach($formatArray as $arr){
        if(!$query->where('mys_ncode',$arr['nationalCode'])->exists()){
           $query->insert([
                'mys_object_id' => $objectId,
                'mys_object_type_id' => $objectTypeId,
                'mys_olp_id' => 4,
                'mys_name' => $arr['name'],
                'mys_fname' => $arr['family'],
                'mys_ncode' => $arr['nationalCode'],
                'mys_paid_price' => $arr['price'],
                'mys_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
           ]);
        }else{
           array_push($repeated, $arr['nationalCode']);
        }
    }
    
    if(!empty($repeated)){
        Session::flash('repeated',$repeated);
    }
```

Now if I test this via uploading an Excel file that contains repeated National Codes which already exists in the DB, it shows the first element in the session `$repeated` (and ignores inserting it) but surprisingly inserts all the others (however, the are all duplicated).

So how can I fix this and ignore inserting repeated National Codes into the Database?

Comment: Write this under the loop(Foreach): $query=DB::table('olympiad_1400');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$repeated = [];

foreach($formatArray as $arr){
    $query=DB::table('olympiad_1400');
    if(!$query->where('mys_ncode',$arr['nationalCode'])->exists()){
       $query->insert([
            'mys_object_id' => $objectId,
            'mys_object_type_id' => $objectTypeId,
            'mys_olp_id' => 4,
            'mys_name' => $arr['name'],
            'mys_fname' => $arr['family'],
            'mys_ncode' => $arr['nationalCode'],
            'mys_paid_price' => $arr['price'],
            'mys_creator_id' => auth()->user()->usr_id,
       ]);
    }else{
       array_push($repeated, $arr['nationalCode']);
    }
}

if(!empty($repeated)){
    Session::flash('repeated',$repeated);
}
```